# Xcode: Is it possible to export SF Symbols and import into Xcode to support older versions?

Tags: xcode, svg, sf-symbols

I already know how to import SF Symbols into Xcode assets:

1. Drag and drop SVG directly
2. Create PDF to represent SVG symbol then add it and configure Attribute Inspector

Cool.. however attempting to export SF Symbol as SVG then add it to assets throws an error:

```
The SVG file provided for the symbol image set ’circle.completed‘ is not suitable: Template format 3.000000 is newer than the version that this software supports (2.100000)
```

I wonder how to support older versions like point 1 instead of point 2 because it is tiring process when creating more than 10 symbols

Comment: There is no version key inside sag file